# PHP file include general query

Tags: php, html, css

In a website say abc.com, I have products, about and contact page. These pages have same Header, Footer section. Should we include header and footer with PHP or We copy/paste HTML/CSS coding done in Index page? Which is the best proctise?

Comment: Include them. Save yourself making the same change in 3+ places. As you site grows, invest time in setting up a CMS.

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP to include your header and footer, that way if you ever need to make a change you only have to edit one file to update the entire website.

Comment: I agree. On a side note, there are more complex approaches like the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which is implemented by many [PHP frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#PHP). If your website/application is likely to grow, you may consider using a framework.

Comment: need to require instead of include... because header and footer necessary part of site....

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a cool method like this:

```
<?php
    $title = "This is the page title"; // Make your header use this
    require "Header.php";
?>
```

Put the page contents in between.

```
<?php
    require "Footer.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The widely accepted way is to have one central file (e.g. index.php) that has the header and footer (you can choose to include them or just have them in the file), and that central file includes the content files in its content area.

There are other ways to do this, but definitely do not copy&paste the same header/footer to many pages as that will make future editing a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

You should use PHP to include them.

Also you could think about using a Template-Engine which would offer you some nice features 
like Nesting content and defining base-layouts which you can extend.

Twig has those features: 
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Answer (score 1):

create file like footer.php 
Set your code in this and you can add this in index.php page like below

```
<?php 
require_once( 'footer.php' );
?>
```

same way for header